# z-index - Absolute element inbetween two others

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have a problem understanding **z-index** properly.

Please have a look at this fiddle I created for you: http://jsfiddle.net/df3EL/

```html
<div id="content">    
    1. Content

    <div id="popup">
        3. PopUp
    </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    2. Footer
</div>
```

I'm aware of positioning and opacity influencing z-index. But with this markup, no matter what I try, the footer is above `1` & `3` or below - never in between.

Is there any way to make the order (1, 2, 3) work, *without changing the html markup*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**z-index** inherits from the parent element

So if your `1` element has a z-index of 100, your `3` element cannot exceed that value in the global scope. In the local scope (within the `#content` element), the z-index will essentially "reset"

So to make your thing work, you'll *need* to change the HTML markup to make each element independent (so they can have sequential z-index in the global scope)

Comment: Ahhh, the **global scope**. That's the bit I was missing. Thank you, Sir!

Comment: No problem - hope it helps!

Comment: Yep helped, but they can't be in the same div. `2` Footer is full-width and content is 960px :/

Answer (score 2):

if you want popup be hover footer, just set index for footer and popup : http://jsfiddle.net/df3EL/1/

```
div {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 20px;
}

div#content {
    display: block;
    height: 150px;
    width: 250px;
    background: #eee;
    position: relative;
}

div#footer {
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    width: 250px;
    background: #eeefc0;
    position: relative;
    left: 25px;
    top: -25px;
    z-index: 1;
}

div#popup {
    display: block;
    height: 140px;
    width: 100px;
    background: #C0C0EF;
    position: relative;
    left: 220px;
    top: -5px; 
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: This works and is the simpliest answer. Too sad I can't remove z-index from my main container. Thanks for answering. Helped me a lot!

Comment: is there a reason why you can not remove z-index from #content ?

Comment: They're old workarounds. Can't risk changing the main container's css, too large project. But I will use your fix instead of changing the markup on the specific pages with JQuery. `$('#content').css('z-index', 'auto');`

Comment: it is just like z-index:auto; or removing z-index from CSS. That what your jQuery does.

Comment: Right, I'm doing _your_ workaround with JQuery. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/df3EL/3/][1]
```

Remove all z-index property except **div#popup**
It should work in modern browser (suppose ie9+, chrome, opera, FF)

But more logical way move **#popup** after **#footer** (may be it should do with javascript when needed to show popup)

Answer (score 0):

You have used `position:relative` for `div#footer` and `div#popup`. Change this to `position: absolute` and change the vaules `top, bottom, left,right` to get the desired result.
By this you won't have to change your html structure.

Comment: Thanks for trying, but this won't work. Still won't be inbetween `1` and `3`.